# Notify and update a source through Multibinding with using StringFormat in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, multibinding

Please analyze following code snippet:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBox_CommandInfo"  Style="{DynamicResource MetroTextBox}"
    IsReadOnly="True" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="This is a textbox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,236,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="154" Width="780" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True">
      <Binding  Path="A" />
      <Binding  Path="B" />
      <Binding  Path="C"/>
      <Binding Path="D" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"
          UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Simply as you can see`TxtBox_CommandInfo` textbox text(Target) value will be modified/formatted with only by `A,B,C` , but the updated text should be  notified to `D` via binding.Model as below:

`A,B,C` => [TexBox.Text] => `D`

Problem is respective source `D` in C# side won't get notified and updated when `TxtBox_CommandInfo.Text` is getting changed.

1. Without any `Converters` how to achieve a solution to this issue?
2. Did I mis-configured the `Multibinding` setting ?

It really requires `StringFormat` feature,therefore without injecting conversion do we have any alternatives with `StringFormat`?

Comment: If it goes only to D, shouldn't it's binding mode be `OneWayToSource` instead of `TwoWay`?

Comment: @RonBeyer Firstly I tried that,It didn't work,updating/notification didn't happen as well

Comment: Why isn't `D` property on the VM simply a getter that combines `A` + `B` + `C`?

Comment: @slugster I wanted retrieve formatted string from `TextBox Text` to `D`

Comment: Totally unclear what you want there. Your `Textbox` is `ReadOnly`. No update possible. Any modification has to be done from A,B,or C. As slugster says format D in VM. `publin string D => $"{A} {B} {C}";` Problem solved.

Comment: Think `A.B,and C are combobox selection` respective those selection `TextBox Text` will be updated with `formatted` manner,What I want is whenever the user selection changed i.e `A,B.C` selection `TextBox Text` will changed that changed `Text` should bind with `D` , rather than direct formatting `D` using `D => $"{A} {B} {C}";`, Want to get it from `TextBox` since Textbox contains some addtional `newline` data.

Comment: public string A {get{return _a;} set{_a =value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(A)); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(D));}

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Thank you for the concern I already have tried those,but not working,also here is my `D` ->  `public string D {get{return _d;} set{_d =value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(D));}`
it's never called/triggered `set` of `D` :(

Comment: @NawedNabiZada is there any conflict with `TwoWay` mode with `<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2}"` ? or should I used `Convertors`?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga You cannot bind TwoWay on a ReadOnly TextBox

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I am new to C# and WPF , then can you please tell me how to disable userinteration(user input) for `TextBox` , only those `A,B,C` can changed the `TextBox Text` value

Comment: I tried with `Mode="OneWayToSource"` also ,it is not working.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want. You have 3 properties A,B and C. You want to show any modification of those properties in a TextBox. That TextBox has to update your fourth property which is D ? am I correct ? if not please modify your question and make clear what you want ? Perhaps a drawing or something

Comment: @NawedNabiZada yeah you are correct.`A,B and C` are already bound with `Comboboxes` and their selection will update `Text` ,since`D` is only intended for getting text of `TextBox` ,that's why I mentioned this `A,B,C => [TexBox.Text] => D` rather than `A,B,C => [TexBox.Text] & D`

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I am really stuck with this issue .. I want to updated Text from `TextBox` , like `textChanged event` , since I am implemented `MVVM` pattern I cannot follow `Code-Behind` approaches and hacks. any Idea?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga You totally missed my point. You don't need a binding to combine the strings back into a property - the target property can just have the code that does it. You are trying a complicated solution for something that is very simple. The fact that there is so many comments here shows that you need to step back and re-evaluate your code.

Comment: @slugster you didn't get it ... it's  okay I given up this approach and  found an alternative approach,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still confused. Don't know exactly what you mean:

What I tried to explain in the comments, here is a solution for that.

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTexts}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=A}" Margin="10"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTexts}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=B}" Margin="10"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTexts}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=C}" Margin="10"/>

        <TextBox Height="80" Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path=D, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C#: (ViewModel)

```
 public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _a;
    private string _b;
    private string _c;

    public string A
    {
        get => _a;
        set
        {
            _a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(A));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(D));
        }
    }
    public string B
    {
        get => _b;
        set
        {
            _b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(B));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(D));
        }
    }
    public string C
    {
        get => _c;
        set
        {
            _c = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(D));
        }
    }
    public string D => $"{A} {B} {C}";

    public List<string> MyTexts { get; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyTexts = new List<string>() { "FHAKWEFJ AWKEEF AWEKF LAEWKF LAWEF", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG" };
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

No hacks, no magic and no events. Plain MVVM

[image]

**EDIT:**
I guess this is what you want (only showing modifications to above code):

```
<TextBox Height="80" Margin="10" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" IsReadOnly="True" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
   <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding  Path="A" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding  Path="B"  Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding  Path="C" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

C#:

```
private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DataContext is MyViewModel dataContext)
        dataContext.D = ((TextBox) sender).Text;
}
```

C# (VM):

```
    private string _d;

    public string D
    {
        get => _d;
        set
        {
            _d = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(D));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the great reply// really appreciate bro.
One thing though! you updated `D` by `A,B,C` and then bind To the `Textbox`,but I am asking other way around, means update `TextBox` using `Multibind A, B, C` and after `Text`has been changed then update `D` ..

Comment: I suppose he wants to avoid property A, B, C in VM. Dunno why,

Comment: Think, All properties there ... this is the flow for the clarity ,
User change three Combobox selections then update `A.B,C` respectively,
Instantaneously `Textbox Text` will be modified using `MultiBind` of `A,B.C` properties, one thing after `Text` has been modified property `D` has to be changed according to `Text` value(Text value does not only contain values from `A,B,C`).

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga you are confusing me even more for every comment you make. What you are asking for is not possible. Your TextBox cannot update any property if it is ReadOnly, you have to do the job from VM

Comment: @FoggyFinder yeap .. it's required user cannot type any text there.. but we need `textchanged` scenario on MVVM

Comment: @Buddhika Chaturanga you still don't understand

Comment: @Buddhika Chaturanga maybe the better solution is to change TextBox to TextBlock - there is no textChanged

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Sorry for the confusing .. your approach is correct too,but here I am dealing with close source, it requires `Mulitibind` scenario, Like above answer you given,Do you have alternative approach using`Multibind` and `Read Only` textbox ? I know as you said for read-only text box no `two-way` mode but `OneWayToSource` right there!!!

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga so, your have a property `D` but you can't change it like in example above or what?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I change it to a `TextBlock` no positive result.`D` wasn't changed. :(

Comment: @NawedNabiZada why did you say like that? :(

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga sorry, that was a joke

Comment: @NawedNabiZada 
You used code-behind => Text-Changed event :| , I already tried that approach, I am struggling with how to find a solution only using `MultiBind` approach without events, Is this like a school project now ?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga There is no rules against using CODE. That code is still part of your VIEW, and totally legit. There are several paths to a solution in WPF, and you are focusing on something that is not possible, and now we have showed you atleast two other ways. So please explain why this is not working for you ? And regarding the school project, it really sound like an assignment you have got and there are clear requirement that has to be fulfilled. If that is true, please state those requirements, so we can try to focus on those. The Solution that you have asked, is already there

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga can we move disscusion to the [WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)?

Comment: okay by the way guys @NawedNabiZada  thank you for your valuable time and effort, I will go with first approach , there is no direct approach with multibind with readonly textbox ... I got it :) :|